# Extjs6 Current Version of Font-Awesome

Tags: font-awesome, extjs6

Greeting all:

Using ExtJS6, sencha workspace.  I would like to download the latest version of Font-Awesome.  What is the correct procedure and location for this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As explained on http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/ - there are various possibilities, you do not even have to download, it is enough to reference the CSS from the CDN.